# Custom DataGridView returns object with columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to create custom DataViewGrid whose constructor accepts some parameter and inside its class definition adds some data to the instance that will be crated.

For example

```
    public partial class DataGridView : Control
    {

        //Constructor
        public DataGridView(string someColumnName)
        {
            // Will not compile, that is the questions, 
            // how to access property Columns inside class definition
            this.Columns.Add(someColumnName);
        }
    }


    //On usage side

    //Initializing the grid with already one column
    var customGrid = new DataGridView("Some Column Name");

    //I want to already have object with this column
    customGrid.Columns.add("Some Column Name");
```

'**this**' does not have property **Columns**. How to add columns in the grid's constructor? Or how to do any other operations inside, which I can do once I create the object, it this case **customGrid** object.

Comment: Where's that constructor being used?

Comment: @LarsTech in some win Forms classes.

Comment: Your form is called DataGridView?

Comment: @LarsTech No, the grid is called like that. Examples of calling c'tor can be in some form.

Comment: So confused at what I'm looking at.  You have a class named DataGridView that inherits from DataGridView?

Comment: @LarsTech DataGridView is class of win control. Code after "//On usage side" is not in that class.

Comment: I know that DataGridView is a control, but your code doesn't compile. How is this a custom DataGridView if you aren't inheriting from DataGridView? I think you need to show more code.

Comment: @LarsTech the question is how to do this "customGrid.Columns.add("Some Column Name");" inside DataGridView class. I have never said that I inherit from DataGridView. More code is coming.

Comment: Obviously, you are inheriting from `Control`, which is not a grid, so there isn't a Columns collection.  You have to inherit from DataGridView, but even then, I think your want will only work if you add the control at run-time.  The designer will barf at your control since it wants a parameterless control it can create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your control to be a DataGridView type control, it would have to either inherit from DataGridView or host a DataGridView control.

So it could look something like this:

```
public class MyGrid : DataGridView {
  public MyGrid(string columnName, string columnHeader) {
    this.Columns.Add(columnName, columnHeader);
  }
}
```

But note though, this won't work if you try to use it in the Form's Designer — it only works with parameterless constructors.  This custom control could only be added at run-time.